# Hide Ionic Menu Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

As there is no default implementation in the Ionic Framework for hiding the the menu(burger)button on the nav bar on a particular page(correct me if I am wrong) I tried an hack to hide it from a page I did this on the controller for the page

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(){

        var element = document.querySelector("[menu-toggle=right]");
        element.style.display = "block";
        element.className = "";
        element.style.display = 'none';

    });
```

But it does not seem to work as the menu button still shows up on the nav bar, I have also tried doing this on the enter and beforeEnter events of the lifecycle of the page but not luck

Comment: Can you create a codepen or fiddle ?

Comment: just curious why you are hiding it ..after hide how user is going to navigate

Comment: @rupesh_padhye I have other kind of navigation implemented for the initial page of the app

Answer (score 0):

`ion-view` API provides `hide-nav-bar` option (boolean).
This will hide the default nav-bar. You can use this to hide the default nav-bar and show your own implementation.

Comment: I stated in my question that I already tried doing this in the enter event, check

Comment: Then can you provide us with a codepen, may be I can help you

Comment: You said you have other kind of navigation implementation for initial page of the app, so hide the navbar and use that.